# VBA Userform posting data twice....sometimes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with a combobox on a sheet "PostHistory" that draws it's data from the "Staff" sheet.  When you press Add on the userform it's suppose to locate the name on the Staff Sheet and replace the date next to the name.  Occasionally, it will replace the date and the date next to the name below it. Using Excel 2016

```
Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Staff").Visible = True
Sheets("Engine").Visible = True

Dim TargetRow As Integer
Dim nameRange As Range

Set nameRange = Sheets("Staff").Range("C3:C200")
TargetRow = Sheets("Engine").Range("D3").Value

Sheets("PostHistory").Range("B3").EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Sheets("PostHistory").Range("B3").Value = txt_date
Sheets("PostHistory").Range("C3").Value = cb_staff
Sheets("PostHistory").Range("D3").Value = txt_post
Sheets("PostHistory").Range("E3").Value = txt_notes


If (Augment.txt_date.Text) = "" Then
GoTo Skip1
ElseIf IsNull(Augment.txt_date.Value) = False Then
End If

For Each cell In nameRange.Cells
If cell.Text = [cb_staff] Then
    cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = txt_date
End If

Next

Skip1:

Unload Augment

Sheets("Staff").Visible = False
Sheets("Engine").Visible = False
Sheets("List").Visible = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Augment.Show

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start: I didn't find the reason why your code should write more than once. But I believe the code below will not write anything twice.

```
Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()
    ' 209
    
    Dim nameRange   As Range
    Dim Fnd         As Range
    Dim Ctls()      As String
    Dim i           As Integer

    Ctls = Split("txt_Date,cb_Staff,txt_Post,txt_Notes", ",")
    If Len(txt_Date) Then
        With Worksheets("Staff")
            Set nameRange = .Range(.Cells(3, 3), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
        End With
        Set Fnd = nameRange.Find(cb_Staff.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then Fnd.Offset(0, -1).Value = txt_Date.Value
    End If
    
    With Worksheets("PostHistory")
        .Rows(3).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        With .Rows(3)
            For i = 0 To UBound(Ctls)
                .Cells(3 + i).Value = Me.Controls(Ctls(i)).Value
                Me.Controls(Ctls(i)).Value = ""
            Next i
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

In principle, you don't need to unhide a sheet in order to read from or write to it. Also, if the sheet to which you write is hidden, there is no point in stopping ScreenUpdating. Finally, I did like the way you found to clear all controls but believe that it will interfere with your management of the list in the combo box. Therefore I showed you another method above.

Oh, yes. I created a userform called `Augment` with one combo box, 3 text boxes and one CommandButton7. I hope that is what you also have.

Comment: Wow, this is much cleaner. I’m going to try it out today and let you know how it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: Worked like a dream! Thank you so much!